# Issue with Hardware Wallet after GUI v0.16 upgrade

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I just upgraded my GUI wallet to the Dandelion version, now I want to make a new wallet with my hardware wallet but it is not letting me, I get this error: "Error writing wallet from Hardware Device. Check application logs". I do not know where the logs are though.

The error log is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see:

> Ledger Monero users, please be aware that a new version of the Ledger Monero App is required in order to properly use GUI v0.16. This release is not yet out, but forthcoming.

As far as I know, the new version of the Ledger Monero App will be out soon.

Meanwhile, you can revert back to using v0.15 until the new Ledger version is released.

**EDIT:** The new version of the Ledger Monero App (v1.6.0) has been released.